# attributeError class intance has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

I've created a MarblesBoard class which I use to instantiate new MarblesBoard objects. I want to solve the board using the Solver class.

```
class MarblesBoard:
    def __init__(self, marbles):
        self.input = list(marbles) 
        print(marbles)
    def switch(self):
        self.input[1], self.input[0] = self.input[0], self.input[1]
        print self.input     
    def rotate(self):
        return self.input[1:] + self.input[:1]
        print self.input
    def is_solved(self):
        if all(self.input[i] <= self.input[i+1] for i in range(len(self.input)-1)):
            return True
            print "True"
        else:
            print "Not solved!"

board = MarblesBoard((3,6,7,4,1,0,8,2,5))
board.switch()
board.rotate()
board.is_solved()
board
```

Works as expected.

```
class Solver:
    def __init__(self, MarblesBoard):
        print self
        self.input = MarblesBoard
    def solve(self):
        if self.input[0] & self.input[1] != 0:
            if self.input[1] < self.input[0]:
                self.input.switch()
            else:
                self.input.rotate()
        else:
            self.input.rotate()

player = Solver(board)
player.solve()
```

Gives me AttributeError: MarblesBoard instance has no attribute '**getitem**' in reference to the self.input lines in the solve function.

Comment: Python printed out a stack trace for you.... be kind and share that information with us. We see those things all the time (well, those of us who don't get it right the first time) and aid in figuring out what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.input` is an instance of the `MarblesBoard` class, which contains a variable also called `input`. `MarblesBoard` doesn't implement a `__getitem__` method to get its internal `self.input` list so you have to reach into it yourself

```
if self.input.input[0] & self.input.input[1] != 0:
```

That first `input` gets the `MarblesBoard` instance and the second `input` gets the `list` inside the instance.

Suppose I implemented `Solver` with a more descriptive variable name

```
class Solver:
    def __init__(self, MarblesBoard):
        print self
        self.marbles_board = MarblesBoard
        ...
```

Then using it would be more self evident

```
    def solve(self):
        if self.marble_board.input[0] & self.marble_board.input[1] != 0:
        ...
```